# Accessing drop down list value from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, html-select

I added a drop down list to my view as shown below.

```
<select id="colorStyle" name="Colours"><option value="0">Red</option><option value="1">Yellow</option>
```

How can I get the selected value from the controller please.

Answer (score 0):

Add the colorStyle as a parameter in the post method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult YourMethod(int colorStyle, ...)
    {
        ...
    }
```